# DirectX Tessellation specific algorithem

Tags: graphics, 3d, directx

I know the for the DX tessellation process, the input is like Domain type ( Triangle, Quad, Isoline) and Tessellation Factor (per Edge) and partition type (like Odd Fractional Even Fractional Integer Pow2) while the output is like a generated point list (like a vertex buffer) and topology (like an index buffer).

The question is what is the real algorithm inside which means how to generate the output base on the input?

Are there any algorithm document describe this? Also why DX choose such an implementation for tessellation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The DirectX 11 tessellation hardware is designed to support a range of different tessellation schemes: Bezier, NURBs, Subdivision, Displacement, etc.

Samples include DirectX SDK [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples) **SimpleBezier11** and **SubD11**, as well as **SilhouetteTessellation** in the [AMD Radeon SDK](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/amd-radeon-sdk/).

See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/07/19/direct3d-11-tessellation.aspx) for a list of other resources including presentations.